# Aeroplane and airplane

Tags: etymology

How has it come to be that we British have the pleasure of saying aeroplane, whereas the US Americans (and possibly others) are only left with airplane?

Comment: Don't we all mostly use *plane* these days? ;)

Comment: @JimiOke seems too plain.

Comment: We Americans just like to deflate English words.  Especially when they seem all puffed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Spelling_and_pronunciation) defines the reason:

> Aeroplane, originally a French loanword with a different meaning, is the [older spelling.][4] The oldest recorded uses of the spelling *airplane* are British.[4] According to the [OED,][5] "*[a]irplane* became the standard American term (replacing *aeroplane*) after this was adopted by the National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics in 1916. Although A. Lloyd James recommended its adoption by the BBC in 1928, it has until recently been no more than an occasional form in British English." In the [British National Corpus,][6] *aeroplane* outnumbers *airplane* by more than 7:1 in the UK. The case is similar for the British [*aerodrome*][7] and American [*airdrome*,][8] although both of these terms are now obsolete. *Aerodrome* is used merely as a technical term in all of Canada, Australia, and New Zealand. The prefixes *aero-* and *air-* both mean air, with the first coming from the Ancient Greek word ἀήρ (āēr). Thus, the prefix appears in *aeronautics, aerostatics, aerodynamics,* aeronautical engineering, and so on, while the second occurs (invariably) in *aircraft, airport, airliner, airmail* etc. In Canada, *airplane* is more common than *aeroplane*, although *aeroplane* is not unknown, especially in parts of French Canada (where it is however used only in English – the French term is avion, and the French word aéroplane designates 19th-century flying machines)

[4][http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=aeroplane&searchmode=none]
[5][Oxford English Dictionary, airplane, draft revision March 2008; airplane is labeled "chiefly North American"]
[6][ British National Corpus. Retrieved 1 April 2008]
[7][Merriam-Webster online, aerodrome. Retrieved 1 April 2008.]
[8][Oxford English Dictionary, airdrome.]
[9][http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aeroplane]

Comment: But you park your automobiles in garages - the French are still winning!

Comment: there is no affinity between the word "automobiles" and "garages". That's why we don't drive "gamobiles"

Comment: @Third idiot. In BE 'aerodrome' was the standard until after WWII, although it was always airfield for smaller strips.

Comment: I realise this is down voted, but It seems to answer my question best.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: @Matt Ellen, I edited my answer

Answer (score 6):

Etymology online says

> 1907, from air (1) + plane; though the original references are British, the word caught on in Amer.Eng., where it largely superseded earlier aeroplane (1873, and still common in British Eng.; q.v.).

so I guess your real question is why "airplane" caught on better. 
It could be the a more common spelling, a simpler connection with "air", which is an English word as opposed to more complex connection to foreign "aero".

However, this is such a nice question to show some ngrams.
British English [corpus](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=aeroplane,airplane&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3):
[image]
American English [corpus](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=aeroplane,airplane&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3):
[image]

There you can see that even in American English it started as a more common word, until replaced in 1920s when airplane overtook.

Comment: But Americans still have Aerospace and Aerodynamics, probably because Airspace is whole other thing, and Airdynamics is too easily confused with air dynamics, plus it sounds stupid.

Answer (score 4):

*Airplane* is a US simplification of *aeroplane*, *aeroplane* having come from the French word *aéroplane*.  The simplification came about because of a combination of people not wanting to bother with the 'o' sound at the end of 'aero', and perhaps a genuine misunderstanding that the *aero-* prefix is intended.  People have have suspected that, as the thing travels through the air, the prefix ought to be *air-* for *airplane*.

As to your aside; yes, I suspect you do prefer that pronunciation because it's the British one.  :-)

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I find it more difficult to transition from *air* to *plane* than I do from *aero* to *plane*, so I don't see this a typical laziness issue.

Comment: Perhaps so, Matt, but try saying it really quickly. You can see where quick-talking, corner-cutting American speech might lead to cutting out the "o" sound. It's the difference between a two-syllable or a 3-syllable word, which can be a significant difference when it comes to American dialect.

Comment: This appears to be personal speculation.